# P-names are comprehensible in the ground model

Tags: set-theory, forcing

If my understanding of $\mathbb{P}$-names $\tau$ is correct, they must be comprehensible by someone living in the ground model $\mathcal{M}$.

However, the value $\tau[G]$ of $\tau$ need not be intelligible in the ground model $\mathcal{M}$ since one requires knowledge of the generic set $G$  in order to understand $\tau[G]$, but such  knowledge is not available in $\mathcal{M}$ as $G \not\in \mathcal{M}$ in general.

Suppose that what I just said is true (please correct me if not), I struggle to see why $\tau$ is comprehensible in $\mathcal{M}$.

---

Here is my definition of $\mathbb{P}$-names (again, correct me if I'm wrong) :

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a forcing notion of $\mathcal{M}$ and let $\alpha \in \text{Ord}$. Define recursively the hierarchy of $\mathbb{P}$-names $\{N_\alpha :~~ \alpha \in \text{Ord}\}$ as follows : $\tau \in N_\alpha$ if and only if every element of $\tau$ is an ordered pair $\langle \sigma, p\rangle$ where $\sigma \in N_{<\alpha}$ and $p \in P$. That is to say
$$\tau ~\subseteq~ N_{<\alpha} \times P ~=~ \bigcup\limits_{\beta < \alpha} N_\beta \times P$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a name is something which exists in the ground model.

Look at the full binary tree. Given any node on the tree, you can't quite say what is the entire real number that it will define, but you can say that the node is limiting your options for which real number you will end up with.

Forcing is about the same. As you "progress along" the forcing poset you gain more information, but you can't quite know what it will entail. But you can know that once you've gone pass a certain condition in the forcing, you will have a certain information regarding the generic filter, or any other name.

And this is the essence of it. You can say, from $\cal M$, which condition forces what, but you can't quite "pack it up" into a single object within $\cal M$. For this you need the generic filter.

Comment: Your example with the binary tree is very enlightening. Thanks.

Just one more thing : is a $\mathbb{P}$-name in $\mathcal{M}$ any collection of pair of a $\mathbb{P}$-name of lower rank and a $p \in P$ OR  any collection that exist in $\mathcal{M}$ of pair of a $\mathbb{P}$-name of lower rank and a $p \in P$ ?

Comment: Put differently, would it be possible for a pair $(\sigma, p)$  to be outside of $\mathcal{M}$ ? Would it still be considered a $\mathbb{P}$-name ?

Comment: Sure, it's usually easy to construct names which are not in $\cal M$. Especially if the model is countable. But $\mathcal M[G]$ is only the interpretation of $\Bbb P$-names which exists in $\mathcal M$. Sometimes we force "over the universe" (so we work in $\cal M$) and then there are no external names, since there is no external universe; and sometimes we work with smaller models (e.g. you take a submodel of $H(\theta)$ and force over it to obtain something) in which case we are usually interested in what names lie in the model and what names don't.

Comment: But if you are only asking about pairs, note that $\cal M$ is closed under pairing, so if $p\in\cal M$ and $\sigma\in\cal M$, then the pair $(\sigma,p)\in\cal M$ as well.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that if $p \mathcal{M}$ and $\sigma \in \mathcal{M}$ then $(\sigma, p) \in \mathcal{M}$ by the pairing axiom since $(\sigma, p) = \big\{\{\sigma\}, \{\sigma, p\}\big\}$ but I could not find any convincing reason why some random collection of such pairs necessarily need to be in $\mathcal{M}$. Your comment answers my question in full. Very many thanks.